# Cannot use mouse wheel on a scrollable div

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, overflow, leaflet

I have two divs, one child of the other. 
The child div is scrollable and is on the parent div (which is a map).
But I cannot use my mouse wheel to scroll the div and using mouse wheel makes the map behind zoom in/out. I a similar manner when I click, I click the map that is under (except the checkboxes on the child).

PARENT

```
<div id="map" class="map" style="position: relative;">
```

CHILD

```
<div id="legend" class="legend" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; width:300px; z-index: 100;>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how I can use my mouse wheel only on the child div and not affect the parent div?

I think it might be relevant to the z-index, because even when I set the z-index of map to 1000, it is still below the legend.

NOTE: the map is a Leaflet map, created in this way:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [45.81, 9.1],
  zoom: 15
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable click/scroll propagation on your `div` element using the `disableClickPropagation` and `disableScrollPropagation` methods of `L.DomEvent`. They will cancel the events so it doesn't bubble up through the DOM:

```
L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(L.DomUtil.get('legend'));
L.DomEvent.disableScrollPropagation(L.DomUtil.get('legend'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your suggestion worked! Can I ask you if the behaviour I had is normal? Shouldn't the div on top be affected by mouse events?
By the way, right now the jQuery mobile slider inside the legend cannot be moved. Can all these be relevant? If you have an answer also for this one I would really appreciate it :) Thanks!

Comment: No thanks need, you're always welcome. This is what SO is for. :) What you experiencing is called "[event propagation](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=event%20propagation%20explained)", this is normal behaviour. Events always bubble up through their ancestors untill you stop it on an element that's in the chain. Otherwise it will continue up to the `body` element. If you're having troubles with the jQuery slider now, it's best you post a new question, comments aren't meant/suited for asking/answering new questions. I'll keep an eye out.